# Question about the new @name comment notification feature

Tags: support

Let's say I want to reply to a comment made by Jeff Atwood.

Which of the following will notify him?

- @Jeff Atwood: I agree with you (this one would be the "Canonical" form, the one that works for sure)
- @Jeff I agree with you
- @Jeff: I agree with you
- @Jeff, I agree with you
- Thanks Jeff, I agree
- The 4 above, but with Atwoof instead of Jeff
- Thanks Jeff Atwood, I agree

I'm asking because I prefer typing just `@Jeff:`, but if he won't get the notification I'll use `@Jeff Atwood:`.

---

**EDIT**: oh well, found the answer on the SO blog, probably should have looked earlier: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/new-improved-comments-with-reply/

Not deleting the question in case other people were wondering the same thing.

Comment: Any of the first 4. The code matches the @ then looks for the first match *in the current set of comments*. See the blog post - http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/new-improved-comments-with-reply/ for more information - I see you found it as the same time I posted this!

Comment: Please see the FAQ: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work-in-stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@name works, even if the user name is **name lastname**

See [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/new-improved-comments-with-reply/)